# SQL Server how to multiply dollar with decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

Given an `account` table that has two columns, which are `account_holder` and `amount`.

Exaample

```
account_holder | amount
------------------------
James Brown    | $2302.03
Phille Jackson | $5643.55
```

Both columns are with the type `VARCHAR(20)`.
What I need to do is to multiply the amount with `5%` to get the interest.

The expected output would be like

```
account_holder | interest
------------------------
James Brown    | $115.10
Phille Jackson | $282.18
```

What I can come up with is to `cast` the `amount` to `money` type. And `concat` a dollar sign with the number after calculation. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: _"Both columns are with the type `VARCHAR(20)`"_ - **why?** ...why aren't you using correct data-types for your columns? (and let me guess... both columns are also `NULL`able too?)

Comment: @Dai It is given. I didn't create the table.

Comment: Are you able to correct the glaring design issues with the table first?

Comment: Do you mean to create another table with the same data and change its type?

Comment: No, I mean to run this: `ALTER TABLE "account" ALTER COLUMN "amount" decimal(10,2) NOT NULL`.

Comment: This would be a good idea. But is it possible to not change the table?

Comment: What, exactly, is making you so apprehensive about _correcting_ your _broken_ table design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach is to change the data type of your column. Since you can not change data type , you can try like below :

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
  account_holder  Varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  Amount Varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO Accounts (account_holder, Amount) VALUES ('James Brown', '$2302.03');
INSERT INTO Accounts (account_holder, Amount) VALUES ('Phille Jackson', '$5643.55');

-- 1. Remove $
-- 2. Convert to decimal
-- 3. Get Interest
-- 4. Again convert to decimal with 2 places
-- 5. Concat $ 

SELECT account_holder, Amount, 
CONCAT('$', CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), RIGHT(Amount, len(AMOUNT)-1)))/20)) Interest
FROM Accounts
```

Comment: Yea, I did it a similar way. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cc5e44926e68a6e3832f7f3834067d33